# Is it possible to add GD/TTF support to PHP without recompiling?

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

I've tried searching for this topic on SO but all the results are about recompiling, rather than about not recompiling.

Has anyone ever used this -> `dl()`
It can be used to load dynamic libraries: http://php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php

Is it possible to load GD and true type font libraries so that I have access to the function  `imagettfbbox()` and `imagettftext()`

I'm using CentOS, Apache, PHP 5.25.

Thanks

Comment: If you have complete access to the server, you can generally configure .so libraries as extensions to PHP, which should allow for adding GD/TTF support. I believe you can compile almost any PHP module as a .so, which is an entire subject on its own. Basic steps would be:
1. Download source
2. cd src/ext/gd
3. phpize
4. ./configure --enable-gd=shared --with-php-config=/path/to/php-config
5. make && sudo make install

Answer (score 3):

Most Linux distributions have a php-gd (or php5-gd) package readily available through the package manager. You just have to find it, and install it.

For Ubuntu and Debian, package name is "[php5-gd](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/php5-gd)"; you should have to type in `sudo apt-get install php5-gd`, and then restart Apache with `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`.

Comment: This isn't enough for bundled gd. It has to be compiled with php, or there is a complicated workaround somewhere.